# How to print multiple values in for loops-methods?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I want the console to writeLine `false` for each ally that does not have a peculiar `item(afaerie_charm)`, and `.25` for each ally that is true in the code:

```
 public bool aFaerie_Charm()
    {
        var allylist = new List<Obj_AI_Hero>();
        allylist.AddRange(HeroManager.Allies);
        bool z = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < allylist.Count; i++) //allylist.count = 4
        {
            z = Items.HasItem((int)ItemId.Faerie_Charm, allylist[i]);
        }
        return z;
    }
```

In the above code, z is true if any of the allies in the list(4 allies) have 'faerie_charm' and false otherwise.

Now, in this part of the code: `allylist[1]` (ally 2) has the peculiar item, so bool returns `true`, then  `faerie = .25;`, and `a2mrs()` returns `.25`, but here's the problem:

the code found that one of the allies has the item and `.25`, but i have no idea which ally has it, it's not returning 'ally 2 has item, and it's value is .25', that's the problem.  Need advice or help please.

```
 public double a2mrs()
    {
        double faerie = 0;


            if (aFaerie_Charm() == true)
            {

                faerie = .25;
            }

        return faerie;
    }
static void Main(String[] args)
{
Console.WriteLine(a2mrs())
}
```

output: .25

problem: from the output .25, i only know one of the allies has the item, i dont know which one has the item.
summary: how do i re-work the code so that it prints something like this:

```
'ally 1 = false'

'ally 2 = .25'

'ally 3 = false'

'ally 4 = false' ?
```

Comment: You need to explain your question more clearly, and likely add more relevant code. I believe there is not enough information in your question to be able to help you.

Comment: You can create a new `class` or a `struct` that can hold multiple values. Alternately, just use a second variable that holds the index of the player with the charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first method returns whether or not the last person in the party has a faerie charm, not whether anyone does.  You'll probably need to refactor your methods so that they return the information for each ally.  You could do this by changing your first method to

```
public List<bool> aFaerie_Charm()
{
    var allylist = new List<Obj_AI_Hero>();
    allylist.AddRange(HeroManager.Allies);
    List<bool> z = new List<bool>();
    for (int i = 0; i < allylist.Count; i++) //allylist.count = 4
    {
        z.Add(Items.HasItem((int)ItemId.Faerie_Charm, allylist[i]));
    }
    return z;
}
```

Then the print:

```
public void printHasFaerieCharm()
{
    List<bool> charms = aFaerieCharm();
    for (int i = 0; i < charms.Count; ++i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ally " + (i + 1) + ": " + (charms[i] ? ".25" : "false"));
     }
}
```

However, I would recommend you adjust the first method so it takes a parameter of the item you want to check for and uses that instead, that way you can reuse it when you want the same information for other items.  You could do something similar with the second method to change what it prints when the item is found (and which item to find), or even add that information to the item's class (so it would be called as something like `printWhoHasItem(ItemId.FaerieCharm)` and look something like `"ally i: " + ItemId.Message`).

Comment: cannot convert 'bool' to 'list.bool'

Comment: @AdanRamirez Sorry, I had forgotten to change the initialization of `z`, it should work now.

Comment: i chose your answer because it's simple and easy to learn, im sure the dictionary thing is much faster/efficient but it's too complex for me, this is the best answer at my level, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well this code is wrong in every aspect. You do realize that result of aFaerie_Charm() is always the result of check for last ally from array?

First of all can't mix booleans with doubles on that stage of code. You need to decide on one of them (based on your use case) and interpret it when it's needed.

You need either return Dictionary from aFaerie_Charm() and in that dictionary you'll add KeyValuePair for each ally in your array, where Key is name of that ally and Boolean is either true or false. Or alternatively you can make aFaerie_Charm accept input parameter of ally and return boolean for that particular ally.

And at the end, you loop through that Dictionary and interpret that boolean anyway you want for display purpose.

In Linq you'll do something like that:

```
// Create dictionary, keys are names of allies, values says if that particular ally has "charm" or not
Dictionary<String, Boolean> allyData = (from x in HeroManager.Allies select new { Name = x.Name, HasCharm = Items.HasItem((int)ItemId.Faerie_Charm, x) }).ToDictionary(y => y.Name, z => z.HasCharm);
```

And now displaying:

```
// Loop through dictionary
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Boolean> a in allyData)
{
    // Display ally's name and if that ally has "charm" then print ".25" and print "false" otherwise 
    Console.WriteLine("%s = %s", a.Key, (a.Value ? ".25" : "false"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more line to your method like this:

```
    public bool aFaerie_Charm()
    {
        var allylist = new List<Obj_AI_Hero>();
        allylist.AddRange(HeroManager.Allies);
        bool z = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < allylist.Count; i++) //allylist.count = 4
        {
            z = Items.HasItem((int)ItemId.Faerie_Charm, allylist[i]);
            //You got 'z' now print  a line
            Console.WriteLine("Ally " + (i + 1) + ": " + z ? ".25" : "false");
        }
        return z;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, You can do this simple thing

In aFaerie_Charm method instead of bool return int

On that aFaerie_Charm method in the if block if HasItem returns true then you return index (i) value or else return -1.

Now in your a2mrs method check it is >0 or less than 0

So if > 0 then you have the index value so you can use that.

However in  aFaerie_Charm  method guess you need one break statement in for loop. Please check

Comment: Please let me know why this is voted down.. This is simple and quick fix.

Comment: I didnt vote it down, thanks for ur input im seeing all the answers and trying to put it in the code, il post the answer.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because the Adam Ramierez asked to print out all the allies, not just the first one that actually has the item.

Comment: Well I gave this answer based on his 1st post. That is why also asked if he needs a break statement